# Project 2D points onto Circle/Curve

Tags: geometry, coordinates, computational-geometry, coordinate-transformation, polar-coordinates

I have a list of XY points which represent text in a "dot matrix" form. The origin of the first point in the set in the set is 0,0(upper left point). (I can change the points to incremental coordinates too)

I would like to project or wrap the points around a radius like so:
[image]

I've tried to follow this answer, but the results are not what I expect:
[How To Project Point Onto a Sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604132/how-to-project-a-point-on-to-a-sphere)

I've also tried converting to Polar coordinates and imposing 
the R coordinate to determine the Theta and the convert back to cartesian, but that does not work either.

For example, the letter T produces this which should then be projected to the curve:

```
0, .0
0.1, .0
0.2, .0
0.2, .-0.1
0.2, .-0.2
0.2, .-0.3
0.2, .-0.4
0.2, .-0.5
0.2, .-0.6
0.3, .0
0.4, .0
```

What is the process to get my points to follow a radial curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to curve around a circle centered at (`cx`, `cy`) with radius `r`, using dots with `size` (diameter) 0.1.

The distance, `d` the center of a dot at (`x`, `y`) is from center of the circle is:

`d = r + y - size / 2`

(I've subtracted `size / 2` to get the position of the center of dot)

The angle `theta` (in radians) around the circle is:

`theta = (x + size / 2) / r`

The position of the dot is then:

`dx = cx + d * cos(theta)
dy = cy - d * sin(theta)`

Here's an example using SVG and Javascript

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('curve-text');
var NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var points = [
    [0, 0],
    [0.1, 0],
    [0.2, 0],
    [0.2, -0.1],
    [0.2, -0.2],
    [0.2, -0.3],
    [0.2, -0.4],
    [0.2, -0.5],
    [0.2, -0.6],
    [0.3, 0],
    [0.4, 0]
];

var cx = 2;
var cy = 2;
var r = 2;
var size = 0.1;

drawCircle(cx, cy , r - 0.7);

var circumference = Math.PI * 2 * r;
var angle = 360 / circumference;
var radians = 1 / r;

// Add 12 copies of the letter T around the circle
for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        addDots(points[i][0] + j, points[i][1], size, cx, cy, r)
    }
}

function drawCircle(cx, cy , r) {
    var circle = document.createElementNS(NS, 'circle');
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', cx);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', cy);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', r);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'none');
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'black');
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '0.02');
    svg.appendChild(circle);
}

function addDots(x, y, size, cx, cy, r) {
    var dotR = size / 2;
    var d = r + (y - dotR);
    var theta = (x + dotR) / r;

    var x = cx + d * Math.cos(theta);
    var y = cy - d * Math.sin(theta);

    var dot = document.createElementNS(NS, 'circle');
    dot.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x);
    dot.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y);
    dot.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', dotR);
    svg.appendChild(dot);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4 4" id="curve-text" width="200" height="200">
</svg>
```

Comment: The missing link for me was the dot size/radius Thank you for the excellent answer!

Comment: @GisMofx Yeah, that's the tricky bit. I didn't really explain it, but basically, an angle of 1 radian sweeps out a length of r (the radius of the circle), so to sweep out a length of d, you need an angle of d/r radians.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the (X, Y) coordinates as if they were (Θ, R) polar coordinates (in this order), and convert to Cartesian.

Experiment a little to understand the effect of horizontal or vertical translation *before* the transformation, as well as h/v scaling. Ensure that for all points R > r, the radius of the circle.